# jqgrid autowidth and shrinkToFit not fitting exaclty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I have created a page which loads many grids into the page when the page loads.  The idea is that all the grids need to adjust the width to fit the width of the page when the page loads.  This works *perfectly* for the **1 grid** that is visible when the page loads, using these options:

```
    shrinkToFit: true,
    autowidth: true,
```

[image]

Notice that the columns fit perfectly, and no horizontal scroll bar shows up.  All the other grids that load in hidden areas of the screen, using the same options above, do not load correctly:

[image]

I tried to fix this issue by using a method to manually set the width, using the `setGridWidth`, setting the width of the hidden grids to the width of the 1st grid, which is the right width.  Using this method, the width of the hidden grid is correct, but then the `shrinkToFit` option is not setting the width of the columns correctly, see here:

[image]

While the grid looks almost correct, you can see the column widths **do not fit correctly** so the horizontal scroll bar shows up.  This becomes an even bigger problem when I get the grid which loads many subgrids.  It becomes a mess:

[image]

The horizontal scroll bars take up too much space, and I wish the `shrinkToFit` would work correctly, it would be really neat and clean.

I hope I explained the problem well enough, does anyone know how I can get the `shrinkToFit` option to work correctly even for these grids which get loaded in hidden areas of the page?  Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is the code for the definition of the subgrids.  You can see I use `setGridWidth` at the end:

```
    ...
    subGrid: true,
    subGridOptions: {
        "plusicon"  : "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
        "minusicon" : "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
        "openicon"  : "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e",
        // load the subgrid data only once
        // and the just show/hide
        "reloadOnExpand" : true,
        // select the row when the expand column is clicked
        "selectOnExpand" : true
    },
    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
        var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
        var po_num =  jQuery('#po_list').jqGrid ('getCell', row_id, 'po_num');
        $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table></div>");
        jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
            url:"/phpAJAX/Master/master_grid_v1.php",
            datatype: "xml",
            shrinkToFit: true,
            autowidth: true,
            mtype: 'POST',
            postData:{
                arg1:'pos',
                po_num:po_num
            },
            colNames:[
                'Row ID',
                ...
            ],
            colModel:[
                {width:20,name:'row_id', index:'row_id',editable:false,hidden:true},
                ...
            ],
            loadonce:true,
            pager: pager_id,
            sortname: 'row_id',
            sortorder: "asc",
            height: '100%'
        }).setGridWidth($("#inv_list").width()*.95);
    }
```

Comment: It would be important to see some more implementation details or simple demo with two grids. For example: do you use jqGrids inside of jQuery UI Accordion? You can use `activate` callback or `accordionactivate` event and call `setGridWidth` inside. You need just get the width of parent div which contains the grid and set it using `setGridWidth`. Important to remark that the second parameter of `setGridWidth` (`shrink` parameter) can be helpful you you. The last question: do you use `autowidth: true` option for subgrids too?

Comment: Hi @Oleg, Yes the hidden grids are contained within the hidden parts of the jQUery UI Accordion.  I will try using `setGridWidth` in the activate callback and see if that works.  And, yes, I am using `autowidth:true;` in the subgrids.  I have put the subgrid definition code in the question.